# How to visit Capilano Suspension Bridge Park and Stanley Park from Vancouver Airport?

Tags: luggage, canada, airport-transfer, vancouver, yvr

Suppose I have ten hours waiting time in Vancouver airport, I want to visit Capilano Suspension Bridge Park then Stanley Park. What is the efficient way to do it? I don't want to miss my flight.

My flight will land in the airport around 11 am and take off in 10 hours.
Here are the issues:

1. I have a big luggage, I am not sure should I pick up it? The flight is from China to USA. just stop at Vancouver for connection flight.
2. I have a carry on baggage, I don't want to carry it in my visiting. I only want to bring a camera.
3. I don't want to rent a car or bicycle. I would like take skytrain or free shuttle or walking.
4. Of course I have to consider eating meals time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking about Capilano Suspension Bridge, which is handy to know if you get lost and are struggling to find it.

In terms of the luggage, that will depend on you, as will food time.

From the airport, you'd get the Canada line (the only option) sky train in to Waterfront (the end of the line).  As you leave the station, you'll see the sea-bus terminal.  Hop onto a seabus (boat) across to the other side (they only go to one place).  At the other side, walk out quickly and into the bus area, and look for the bus to Grouse Mountain.  It also stops at Capilano Suspension Bridge.

Coming back, you can repeat this in reverse, looking for a bus to Lonsdale Quay, then the seabus over to Waterfront, noting on your right that you'll see the big Stanley Park.  Decide now if you want to walk there. If so, that's easy. If not, get out at Waterfront and walk up Granville until you hit W Georgia. Buses heading to the right will be going to Stanley Park.

Depending on the bus, some will go through the park and over the bridge.  A nicer option is to get off at Stanley Park and walk right around the entire park, which will give you a great view of the city, the Lions Gate bridge and the park.  (Note, the bridge is on the far side of the park to the city).  It's about a 12km walk to do the full circuit though, so be prepared if you're considering this.

Bonus tip: If you have Google Maps and a smartphone, as you exit the Waterfront station you'll see a Starbucks, as well as at Lonsdale Quay.  There's also one at W Georgia and Granville (well, two), and one near Stanley Park.  They have free wifi, which is handy for checking bus times on Google Maps, and your flight updates. There's also free wifi at the airport.

Comment: @Love: note that this is really *a lot* to do in a 10 hour layover - you want to be back at the airport 2 hours early to be safe, and I'd say that 8 hours is not enough to do all of the above (especially walking around Stanley Park) and still have time to eat. Better pay attention to the clock and have a safety margin for unexpected problems - when I visited Stanley Park and wanted to go back, I found that all buses were cancelled due to the Canada Day parade.

Comment: There's also the [Lynn Canyon Suspension Bridge](http://lynncanyon.ca/), which is free to visit (Capilano is rather pricey). However, it takes a little longer to get to, so may not be suitable for the OP as they're going to be rather short on time!

Comment: I just came back. There is a free shutter service in Canada Place provided by the park.