# Do we need to pick up our luggages and re-check them in YVR?

Tags: air-travel, transit, yvr

My family will fly from Sydney Australia (SYD) to Newark USA on Air Canada but connecting at Vancouver (YVR). Do we need to pick up our luggage in YVR and recheck in them? If we have to, where can we recheck in the luggage?

We have 8 hour connecting time in YVR, are we able to go to Vancouver for sightseeing?

Comment: Are both your flights Air Canada or an alliance member? You're flying direct to Vancouver from Sydney and then direct to Newark from Vancouver?  And assume Australian passports?

Comment: YVR provides a handy connection tool: http://www.yvr.ca/en/navigating-yvr/passenger-guides/connecting-through-YVR.aspx

Comment: Both flight are Air Canada:  AC34 and AC548. We are US passport holders.

Answer (score 5):

Using [YVR's handy connections tool](http://www.yvr.ca/en/navigating-yvr/passenger-guides/connecting-through-YVR.aspx), you can put in that you're arriving internationally, changing to fly to the US, and both flights are on Air Canada.

The result:

> Arrive at YVR
>
> Most passengers will have their luggage checked-through to their final
>   destination, so you will not claim your checked-bags at YVR. Please
>   ensure you have a boarding pass and baggage claim tags for your
>   connecting flight. if you do not, contact your airline for
>   instructions, you may have to check-in again.
>
> Follow signs to USA Connections.

More details about US customs and the like exist on the page for you to peruse.

**Note however**, that if your flight arrives before 7.30am, or after 6.30pm, there is a different procedure, also listed on that page.

As for departing the airport, yes, this is possible - a friend did this on his connecting Air Canada flight - came out to meet me for a few hours.  The downtown core is about 35 min away by Skytrain.  I recommend this other question - [How to visit Capilano Suspension Bridge Park and Stanley Park from Vancouver Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/19459/101) which has details on getting in from the airport to see a few of the sights, and [this question shows the various costs of transport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1668/101), if you want to consider something other than the very convenient, clean and safe Skytrain.

Comment: @YanYuan no problem! Please do accept the answer if it answers your question :)  And enjoy Vancouver if you get into the city - it's fantastic (I lived there for a year)